# Possible difference between "Safari on iPad" and "Safari on iPhone" on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, mobile-safari

I have a project involving Google Maps API and some JavaScript codes. The page is build upon jQuery Mobile. I have the web page tested on Chrome, FireFox, Opera and IE on desktop, and on various mobile phones as well.

It doesn't work only on iPhone (4, nor 5). I mean, it's all good under Android, WP8, Chrome iPhone simulator, and even working perfectly on an iPad (Air, if matters).

It appears to be that Google Maps API is not loaded at all. It should be initialized after page load, and then show a map inside the page. But there's nothing. Also there's no alert about querying user's location, which does happen when using an iPad.

The safari on iPhone is the same version as that on my iPad, OS 7.0.4, Apple WebKit 537.51.1, Safari 9537.53. The devices are connected to the same WiFi network. Due to lack of a Mac I can't use the remote debugging function right now.

Any brief ideas about what's wrong with the application? I suspect it's inside JavaScript but I could be wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: ”The page is build upon jQuery Mobile”. My guess is, it might be a jQuery mobile issue. Try loading the GMaps APIs and functions in a non-jquery html page, and check if it's working that way.

Comment: @adrian7 That sounds a good point. I'll try strip the jQM and see if it works.

Comment: @adrian7 I have removed everything jQM related, CSS and JS. The problem remains the same. It works everywhere else (although ugly) but not on iPhone.

Comment: you mean the GMaps apis does not load?

Comment: @adrian7 I'm not sure of it's GMaps API not loaded or there's any JS errors preventing the map being displayed. Just can't distinguish between them.

Comment: Anyway I kind of find the problem here. It's because the call to navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition fails anyway on an iPhone. Wired.

Comment: well, you can write a callback/init function to display an alert upon loading gmaps apis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem and solved it.

It is because the location service is disabled for safari (by default), on iPhone. However it's enabled on my iPad (not sure if it's default) so that I get different reaction from the location service API.

I have to put an alert message for iOS users when detecting that location service is disabled. After it's enabled in the privacy settings on the device, the application works perfectly on all devices.

The patch code is [here](https://github.com/osulp/CorvallisTour/commit/d23bd710456414948b7dd49c389a15d7722ee0bb) for those who need.